# Angular 10: repeat the same http request after obtaining the refresh token

Tags: javascript, angular, angular10, refresh-token

I am trying to achieve the following in my HTTP calls

1. If an API request returns 401  then call the refresh token endpoint to get the token.
2. Retry the same HTTP call with the updated token

Here is the relevant code

```
// this method invoke when the HTTP interceptor returns 401 status code

handle401(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    if (!this.refreshTokenInProgress) {
      this.refreshTokenInProgress = true;
      this.refreshTokenSubject.next(null);
      return this.getToken((data: any) => {
        this.refreshTokenInProgress = false;
        this.refreshTokenSubject.next(data);
        request = request.clone({ headers: request.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${data}`) });
        return next.handle(request);
      })
    } else {
      return this.refreshTokenSubject.pipe(
        filter(token => token != null),
        take(1),
        switchMap((accessToken) => {
          request = request.clone({ headers: request.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${accessToken}`) });
          return next.handle(request);
        })
      );
    }
  }
```

Obtain the refresh token

```
getToken(cb: any) {
    let poolData = {
      UserPoolId: environment.cognitoUserPoolId, // Your user pool id here
      ClientId: environment.cognitoAppClientId // Your client id here
    };
    let userPool = new CognitoUserPool(poolData);
    let cognitoUser = userPool.getCurrentUser();
    cognitoUser?.getSession((err: any, session: any) => {
      const refresh_token = session.getRefreshToken();
      cognitoUser?.refreshSession(refresh_token, (refErr, refSession) => {
        
        const userToken = localStorage.getItem('token');
        cb(userToken);
      });
    })
  }
```

While executing I am getting the new token from the `getToken` method, but the retry of the same HTTP call is not happening.

The execution of HTTP request stops after obtaining the refresh token from the `getToken` method.

Can somebody please help on this issue

Answer (score 0):

if you use catchError should return Observable

your getToken function has not return

maybe you can watch this

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73364684/19768317

Comment: Please add supporting context to your answer, quoting where the getToken is not returning, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you want to get `userToken` from `getToken()`. `getToken()` should return something, right now it's not returning anything. If some methods like `getSession` or `refreshSession` are async methods then those should be waited too.

```js
 async handle401(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    if (!this.refreshTokenInProgress) {
      this.refreshTokenInProgress = true;
      this.refreshTokenSubject.next(null);
      const token = await this.getToken(); // put "cb" param here, wait for returned token, then continiue
        this.refreshTokenInProgress = false;
        this.refreshTokenSubject.next(token);
        request = request.clone({ headers: request.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`) });
        return next.handle(request);

    } else {
      return this.refreshTokenSubject.pipe(
        filter(token => token != null),
        take(1),
        switchMap((accessToken) => {
          request = request.clone({ headers: request.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${accessToken}`) });
          return next.handle(request);
        })
      );
    }
  }

getToken(cb: any) {
    let poolData = {
      UserPoolId: environment.cognitoUserPoolId, // Your user pool id here
      ClientId: environment.cognitoAppClientId // Your client id here
    };
    let userPool = new CognitoUserPool(poolData);
    let cognitoUser = userPool.getCurrentUser();
    cognitoUser?.getSession((err: any, session: any) => {
      const refresh_token = session.getRefreshToken();
      cognitoUser?.refreshSession(refresh_token, (refErr, refSession) => {
        
        const userToken = localStorage.getItem('token');
        cb(userToken);
        return userToken;
      });
    })
  }
```

Comment: Should you not add return statement before `cognitoUser?.getSession(` ?

Comment: `getToken()` is is returning as callback function and i m getting the value in the callback